# How to make react slick carousel resizable when I zoom out?

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-slick

So like the title says, what I am trying to achieve is that when I zoom out, I want my carousel to be 100% width of the screen all time, here is what I mean by that. Right now when I zoom out, my carousel looks like this:

[image]

But when it is 100% zoom, a.k.a my normal screen it looks like this:

[image]

So, how do I make this be resizable meaning it is going to be like it is on a normal screen (100%) on every zoom.

Here is my code:

```
const Works = () => {
    var settings = {
        centerMode: true,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerPadding: "10px",
        customPaging: (i) => <div className="works-dots"></div>,
        arrows: false,
    };

    return (
        <div className="mainWorks-container">
            <div className="works-popup-container">
                <h3 className="works-title">WORKS</h3>
                <div className="works-popup-image-container">
                    <Slider {...settings}>
                        {worksImages.map((image, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index} className="works-image">
                                    <img
                                        src={image.image}
                                        alt={image.alt}
                                        className="works-popup-image"
                                    />
                                    <div className="image-overlay">
                                        <h3>{image.title}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </Slider>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="works-button-container">
                <a href="/">
                    <Button text="View Works" isFilled={false} type="border" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Works;
```

This is my Works.js component.

```
.mainWorks-container {
    height: 675px;
    position: relative;
}

.works-popup-container {
    height: 780px;
    width: 986px;
    background: url("../../../images/gradient-background.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.works-title {
    margin-top: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.works-popup-image-container {
    .slick-list {
        position: relative;
        left: -30%;
        width: 105rem;
    }
    .works-image {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 8rem;
        width: 385px;
        height: 513px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0px 70px 100px -40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        img {
            width: 385px;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: contain;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .image-overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 91.7%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            color: white;
            opacity: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            word-break: break-word;
        }

        .image-overlay:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}

.works-dots {
    background: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.75);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.works-dots:hover {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.slick-active {
    .works-dots {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
    }
}

.works-button-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And this is my worksStyles.scss file.

If anyone knows how to do this, I would be thankful.